# Looking for Android 7 stock ROM Moto G5S plus XT1804

Tags: 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g5s-plus

I want to flash the official stock ROM that came with my Moto G5S plus phone XT1804 i.e. India build. I searched but so far could only find the Android 8 ROM.

Why am I looking for this? I updated my phone to Android 8.1 December 2018 update. After that VoLTE stopped working. I can access the internet, send SMSes but can't make or receive calls. The VoLTE provisioned option in Phone Information is greyed out. I think that if I downgrade to nougat I may be able to get back my VoLTE. I have flashed other roms, including custom roms, too but no luck so far.

Comment: be aware other partitions like persist dsp modem may have important role too, always flash full stock ROM + firmware. also check your IMEI https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3782387